# CSS target HTML tag, style name and class name

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some markup below and what i want to do using css is target the 3 following points.

- img
- style*=right
- class=media-element

I have tried the following code which fails

```
img[style*="right"][class="media-element"] {margin-left:10px;}
```

Using the following to select the style works

```
img[style*="right"]...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
img.media-element[style*="right"] {margin-left:10px;}
```

No need to use attribute equal selector if you know your exact class name. Use `.` ( dot ) notation instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your attribute selector `[class="media-element"]` looks for an exact match of the *entire* value of the `class` attribute. It will match the element only if the attribute as it appears in the markup is exactly `class="media-element"`, with no other class names. Otherwise, it will fail.

If you're selecting by class name, you really should be using a class selector:

```
img[style*="right"].media-element {margin-left:10px;}
```

You should only use an attribute selector with the `class` attribute if you have a very good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many classes inside `class=''`, then `[class="media-element"]` is not going to match any element,

what you can do alternately is,

```
img[style*="right"][class*="media-element"] {margin-left:10px;}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4t5qmw3/1/